# Google App Engine Security

Tags: web-application, webserver, cloud-computing, confidentiality, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google App Engine Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7598/google-app-engine-security)

I am writing a master thesis concerning security of certain applications, and as a part of it I want to write a web app on Google App Engine and test how secure it is.

Does anyone know if there was any study done on the security of GAE in comparison to other servers for web apps?

What would you say are the most likely weak chains in creating a web app on GAE an handling users' valuable information? For example, is the web app only as secure as the web admin's password, or can there be some other security measures in place to prevent even the admins from accessing users' information stored with the app?